# Scala List.updated

Tags: scala, immutability, scala-collections

I am curious about List.updated. What is it's runtime? And how does it compare to just changing one element in an ArrayBuffer? In the background, how does it deal with copying all of the list? Is this an O(n) procedure? If so, is there an immutable data structure that has an updated like method without being so slow?

An example is:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
val list2 = list.updated(2, 5) --> # list2 = (1,5,3)
var abuf = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)
abuf(2) = 5 --> # abuf = (1,5,3)
```

Comment: For this kind of question, it is often useful to [take a look a the source code](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src//library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The time and memory complexity of the `updated(index, value)` method is linear in terms of `index` (not in terms of the size of the list). The first `index` cells are recreated.
2. Changing an element in an `ArrayBuffer` has constant time and memory complexity. The backing array is updated in place, no copying occurs.
3. This `updated` method is not slow if you update elements near the beginning of the list. For larger sequences, `Vector` has a different way to share common parts of the list and will probably do less copying.

Answer (score 5):

`List.updated` is an O(n) operation (linear).

It calls the linear `List.splitAt` operation to split the list at the index to get two list `(before, rest)`, then builds a new list by appending the elements in `before`, the updated element and then the elements in `rest.tail`.

I'm not sure - this would have to be tested, but it seems that if the updated element was at the start of the list, it may be pretty efficient as in theory getting `rest` and appending `rest.tail` could be done in constant time.

Comment: Thanks huynhji, does Vector do this differently?

Comment: @user592419, `Vector` uses a trie graph of array of size 32 (I think). So updating an element would probably require O(log(n)) to update the trie and an array creation and copy of 32 elements. Should be pretty efficient for large size.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose performance would be O(n) since list doesn't store index to each element and implemented as links to next `el` -> el2 -> el3` so only list.head operation are O(1) as fast.
You should use IndexedSeq for that purpose with most common implmentation Vector.

Although it doesn't copy any data so only 1 value are actually updated in memory.
In general all scala immutable collections dosn't copy all data on modification or creation of updated new instance. It is key difference with Java collections.

Comment: The key difference with Java collection is that Java collections are not immutable. Besides, it is wrong to say that the Scala "immutable collections dosn't copy all data on modification or creation of updated new instance". They uses structural sharing whenever possible, but otherwise, copying *will* occur. A `Vector` with less than 32 elements updated this way would be copied every time entirely, for instance.

Comment: 32 is constant so all updates to immutable collection is O(1) in updates. OK 1 is wrong by I mean constant time there. If not immutability, what then the key difference in one word?